# Passing multiple values from a loop to an array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

```
    $stmt = $db->get_products();

$products = array();
foreach($stmt as $items){
    $products = array('asin'=>$items['asin']);
}

print_r($products);
```

Assuming my `$stmt` contains 4 values from my database, my problem is that I only get the first data in my `print_r`, not all the data from my database. But when I echo inside the `foreach` it displays the expected output but when passing it to an array it only contains one value.

Answer (score 2):

You should replace

```
$products = array('asin'=>$items['asin']);
```

with

```
$products[] = array('asin'=>$items['asin']);
          ^--- Missing bracket
```